# Hyphenation of compound adjective or quantifier when referring back to antecedent

Tags: grammaticality, adjectives, compound-adjectives, quantifiers, antecedents

Example: She ate one or more apples, and each apple of the one-or-more apples was either red or green.

In the example, if "one or more apples" is the antecedent, should the reference back (i.e., "the one-or-more apples") be hyphenated?

My thinking is that "one-or-more" in "the one-or-more apples" works as a compound adjective or "compound quantifier" when referring back to the antecedent of the example, and hyphenation of the compound adjective or quantifier improves readability. Readability is not an issue in the example, but repeated references back to such an antecedent with the hyphenation seem to be easier to read in longer forms of writing.

Comment: "one or more apples" would not take a hyphen. It is not a compound adjective at all. "She ate one or more apples, and each one was either red or green". One would not repeat one or more apples. But this question is not really good for this forum. It should be asked on ELL.

Comment: I understand that the example sentence can be simplified to eliminate the reference back. It's intended to be simple example. What if circumstances dictated that you had to refer back a number of times to the example antecedent?

Comment: Your saying refer back thing just does not work in terms of a reason for using hyphens. Once you have defined the thing: one or more apples, you would just refer to apples, imo.

Comment: Referring back to a plurality of apples (i.e., the "more" of the one-or-more apples) excludes a reference back to the single apple (i.e., the "one" of the one-or-more apples). What if circumstances dictated that you had to refer back a number of times to the single apple and the plurality of apples, collectively?

Comment: Sorry, I don't get you now. an/one apple and apples with an s.

Comment: You'll note that patents are replete with "the one or more" (without hyphens).

See https://patents.google.com/?q=(%22the+one+or+more%22)&oq=%22the+one+or+more%22

It seems readability is enhanced by using hyphens, as in "the one-or-more."

Comment: I am not contesting one or more x. I am saying that phrase simply would not take a hyphen. You are claiming that readability is enhanced. It isn't. "Ten or more points are needed to advance to the next round!"

Comment: I wouldn't use the hyphenation for the antecedent--only for the numerous references back, in which "one-or-more" seems to act as a modifier of some sort.

Comment: No, the most one might consider is using quotation marks.

Comment: If I read quotes around "one or more," and we weren't speaking of words and phrases as we are here, I would interpret those quotes as scare quotes, which completely changes the meaning.

"One or more apples" is a quantified collection of apples, and, as such, it is appropriate to refer back to that collection by either "the one or more apples" (w/out hyphens) or "the one-or-more apples" (with hyphens). My question regards what is the most appropriate way to express the compound adjective or quantifier "one or more" in instances /other/ than the antecedent instance.